# Cardinal numbers of Setminus

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Could you help me check the following fact?

Let $A,B,C$ be sets such that $C\subseteq A$ and $C\subseteq B$. Then

$1.$ $|A\setminus C|=|A|−|C|$

$2.$ $|A\setminus C|=|B\setminus C|$ if and only if $|A|=|B|$

where $|A|$ is the cardinal number of $A$ and $A\setminus C$ is the set of all elements of $A$ that are not elements of $C$.

I'm worrying about an infinite cardinal number.

Thank you.

Comment: 2: follows from 1., at least if |.| is finite for all sets.

Answer (score 0):

If $A,C$ are infinite with $C \subseteq A$, even only countably infinite, you cannot really say anything about $|A\setminus C|$: it could be any finite number, including $0$, or countably infinite (so $\aleph_0$). So there is no really good way to define $|A| - |C|$ for  this case, so the rule would hold. Substraction of infinite cardinals is not really done.

Rule 2 will be true in the left to right , as $|A \setminus C| = |B \setminus C|$ gives us a bijection $f$ between  $A \setminus C$ and $B \setminus C$, which we extend by the identity on $C$ to get a bijection between $B$ and $A$, so $|A| = |B|$. However the reverse does not hold with infinite sets: $C = \mathbb{N}, A = \mathbb{N} \cup \{-1\}, B = \mathbb{N} \cup \{-1,-2\}$ shows that while $|A| = |B| = \aleph_0$, the differences have size 1 resp. 2.

Comment: Thank a lot Henno Brandsago

Comment: For (1), if I prove (A∖C)∪C=A⇒|A∖C|+|C|=|A|⇒|A∖C|+|C|−|C|=|A|−|C|⇒|A∖C|=|A|−|C|. Is it correct?

Comment: @user177624 yes, for *finite* sets $C$. Otherwise not necessarily, for the reasons I stated. You cannot substract infinite cardinalities from both sides just like that.

Comment: Yes, for $C$ finite both do hold.